# How can I add fadeIn to my show_hide() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function. When you hover a div, it shows a delete button, and when mouseout, it hides it. Now, I just need to add fadeIn to my show_hide function, instead of just showing directly. How can I do that ?

Html

```
<div onmouseover="show_hide('deletebutton')" onmouseout="show_hide('deletebutton')">

// image 

<div id="deletebutton" style="display:none">DELETE</div>

</div>
```

JS

```
function show_hide(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if (e == null){
    } else {
    if (e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
            else
            e.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe google will give an answer to your question. try googling first :)

Comment: Use jQuery [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn) method.

Comment: I know there is fadeIn() , but how can I integrate it, because its javascript.

Comment: You can use jQuery in JavaScript as jQuery is a library of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery then try this example.

see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wC9Wk1XRAThh4mTWgpTB?p=catalogue)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>fadeIn demo</title>
  <style>
  span {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  div {
    margin: 3px;
    width: 80px;
    display: none;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
  }
  #one {
    background: #f00;
  }
  #two {
    background: #0f0;
  }
  #three {
    background: #00f;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<span>Click here...</span>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>

<script>
$( document.body ).click(function() {
  $( "div:hidden:first" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

*[source](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/#example-0)*

Answer (score 1):

Use `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` methods

```js
  function show_hide(id) {
       var e = $("#"+id);
       if(e.is(":visible")) {
          console.log("if")
          e.fadeOut(500);
       } else {
          console.log("else")
          e.fadeIn(500);
       }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onmouseover="show_hide('deletebutton')">
   <div id="deletebutton" style="display:none">DELETE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**WITHOUT JQUERY**

If you dont want to use jquery you should use *opacity*   insted of  *display*.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" onmouseover="show_hide('deletebutton')" onmouseout="show_hide('deletebutton')">
<div id="deletebutton" style="opacity:0">DELETE</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
*function show_hide(x) {

     var e = document.getElementById(x);
     if(e.style.opacity=="0")
     e.style.opacity="1";
     else
      e.style.opacity="0";

}*
```

**CSS** - to make fade in

```
#deletebutton{
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41j6v74u/)

Answer (score 1):

There are **multiple ways** of achieving this you can use any of the following:

- JavaScript
- JQuery
- CSS3 animantions
- Bootstrap

Using CSS3 animations would be the easiest and most efficient way would be using CSS3. Using **JQuery** you can either use `FadeIn()` or `FadeOut()`. Moreover, you can use `addClass()` or `removeClass()`

I will give you both examples from CSS3 and JavaScript(the way you are doing it). As example of JQuery is already been shown by @Jayesh

### **Using CSS3**

```css
    .myclass {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-top: 25px;
        font-size: 21px;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
        -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
        transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    }
    .mainclass:hover > .myclass  { opacity: 1 }
```

```html
<div class="mainclass">
// image 
  <div class="myclass ">DELETE</div>
</div>
```

---

### Using JavaScript

```js
    function show_hide(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e == null){
        } else {
        if (!e.classList.contains('showClass'))
                e.className += " showClass";
                else
                e.className = "myclass";
       }
    }
```

```css
.myclass {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}
.showClass{ opacity: 1 }
```

```html
<div onmouseover="show_hide('deletebutton')" onmouseout="show_hide('deletebutton')">
// image 
  <div class="myclass" id="deletebutton">DELETE</div>
</div>
```

---

Hope this will help. Thank you.